# Cannot find module X even after deleting import & node_modules npm

Tags: node.js, npm

My issue is the following. I've imported mistakenly a non-existent module, e.g.:

import xy from '@/xy';

and ran npm start resulting in an error "Cannot find module xy". I've removed the import line causing the error, removed node_modules, and package-lock.json and ran npm install but the error persists. What am I missing?

Cheers.